# Finding the inverse of $f(x)=x(x+1)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse-function

This blog entry [Inverse functions: we're teaching it all wrong](https://blogs.ams.org/matheducation/2016/11/28/inverse-functions-were-teaching-it-all-wrong/), warns against swapping variables when finding the inverse of a function.

What would be the general procedure for finding the inverse of $f(x)=x(x+1)$ (domain: $\mathbb{R}$, without swapping dependent and independent variables ?

Comment: What is "the inverse" for a non-bijective function?

Comment: An inverse for a non-bijective function does not exist.

Comment: But your function is not bijective, right? So it has no inverse. We have $f(0)=f(-1)=0$, so it is not injective.

Comment: I found on wolfram alpha that its inverse is: $\frac{1}{2}(-1 \pm \sqrt{4x+1})$. Is it incorrect ?

Comment: Define its domain to make it injective......your inverse function will have 2 values at the same value of $x$, as the $\pm$ suggests.

Comment: That's odd. I didn't know there was a problem with "switching $x$ snd $y$". Geometrically and algebraically one can conclude if point $(x,y)$ is on some relation then the point $(y,x)$ is on that relation's inverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not comment on this "variable swapping" controversy.

Write

$$y=x(x+1)=\left(x+\frac12\right)^2-\frac14$$ yields the solution

$$x=-\frac12\pm\sqrt{y+\frac14}.$$

From this it is clear that we should have $y\ge -\dfrac14$ and that there are two distinct solutions in $y$. Choosing one of the branches, we have the inverse function

$$f^{-1}(x)=-\frac12+\sqrt{x+\frac14}, x\ge-\dfrac14$$

where

$$f(x)=x(x+1), x\ge-\frac12.$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Yves. Could you add how you went from $y=x(x+1)$ to $\left(x+\frac12\right)^2-\frac14$ ?

Comment: I am not entirely clear how did you get $-\frac{1}{4}$ on the right side of your first equation.

Comment: It's just completing the square in $x^2+x$

Comment: Thank you, @saulspatz.

Answer (score 2):

You will first have to define a domain to make the function injective, before finding its inverse.

eg. If you take the domain of $f(x)$ as $\left[ \frac{-1}{2}, \infty \right)$

$$y=x(x+1)$$

$$y=[x^2+(2)\frac{1}{2}x +(\frac{1}{2})^2 ]-\frac{1}{4}$$

$$y=(x+\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}$$

$$x=-\frac{1}{2} \pm \sqrt{y+\frac{1}{4}}$$

Now, since the domain is restricted to be $> \frac{-1}{2}$ we are down to one branch of the $\pm$, specifically the $+$ one.

So,

$$f^{-1}(x)=-\frac{1}{2} +\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{4}}$$

Similarly, if the domain was $(-\infty,-\frac{1}{2}]$, the $-$ branch would be selected.

Here, $$f^{-1}(x)=-\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{4}}$$
$${}$$